# Examples of category-changing reduplication

Tags: morphology

Are there examples of reduplication that clearly changes the syntactic category of a root/stem? I'm thinking of cases like:

pak, n *'tortilla'*

pakpak, v *'make tortillas'*

tap, a *'red'*

tatap, v *'redden'*

The language with pervasive reduplication I know best, Kaqchikel (Mayan), has reduplication turning affect words into intransitive verbs, like the following example, but as far as I know, there aren't cases of reduplication that change core syntactic categories.

witz' *'the sound mice make'*

niwitz'itz' *'he/she/it made the sound mice make'*

Comment: That depends on what you consider a syntactic category. In polysynthetic languages, there's often not much difference between verb, noun, and adjective, for instance, beyond the morphology that's applied. In [Lushootseed](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Lushootseed.html) (Salishan), there are a large number of [reduplication types](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Lushootseed-6.pdf), but they apply to all kinds of roots.

Answer (score 1):

There is Alemannic Verb Doubling where **syntax** ⇔ **morphologic duplication**. Iff the verb subordinates another one, there's duplication of this verb.

```
Er [got *(go) [poschte]]
He  goes  go   shopping

Er [got (*go) (zum    Lädili)]
He  goes       to the shop
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be what the question is asking about.

Comment: I think it does, OP is asking for data where reduplication is linked to change of category; this is an example where syntax (and categories = distribution in syntax) is linked to the doubling of morphemes.

Comment: Interesting example. Out of curiosity, how would Alemannic translate "I want to eat"/"I like to drive" (where, in English, one verb subordinates another) versus "I want some food"/"I like cars"?

Answer (score 0):

In colloquial Spanish, there are examples of reduplication such as *El bebé estaba **llori-llori*** (= "El bebé estaba llorando") that seem to involve non-finite forms of the verb, or deverbal derivations. Depending on how one analyzes such examples, reduplication may be part of the process whereby a verb is converted into a non-verb.

I don't know of any cases in Spanish where a conjugated form of the verb is  reduplicated.

Comment: *el tocatoca* is a popular song.